# Get data from promises with protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm setting up a suite of e2e tests for an angular app using protractor. I'm following a page object model pattern detailed in this [article](http://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/using-page-objects-overcome-protractors-shortcomings). I'm having trouble with a particular test that involves creating a user and verifying that the the data was handled/persisted correctly. The steps in this test are as follows:

1.) Create a user by having protactor send data to a form from a User object and submitting it:

```
//models.js
  TestUser = {
    Title: 'Big Boss Man',
    Email: 'theboss@gmail.com',
  }
```

2.) Verify that the data was correctly handled/persisted by inspecting that data in the newly created user's "Account Details" view. This data is displayed in a table like so:

```
// accountdetails.html
<table class="account-details" summary="Account details">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <th>Title:</th>
       <td class="ng-binding">Big Boss Man</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <th>Email:</th>
       <td class="ng-binding">theboss@gmail.com</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

3.) Use a simple helper method which compares the matching key/value pairs of two passed in objects using jasmine's toEqual() method:

```
compareTwoObjects: function(object1, object2) {
Object.keys(object1).forEach(function(key) {
  expect(object2[key].getAttribute('value')).toEqual(object1[key]);
});
```

The problem: how can I write a method that will find the table using an element selector, burrow down into the `<th>` and `<td>` elements, get their text values, and build an object of key/value pairs that I can compare with the original `TestUser` object?  Because I obviously don't understand promises very well, the following is what I came up with:

```
getUserData: {
  get: function() {
    var userData = {};
    $$('table[summary="Account details"] tbody tr')
    .then(function(rowElements) {
      rowElements.forEach(function(rowElement) {
        rowElement.$('th').getText().then(function(label) {
          rowElement.$('td').getText().then(function(text) {
            userData[label.slice(0,-1)] = text;
            // success! logs {Title: 'Big Boss Man', Email: 'theboss@gmail.com'}
            // on completion of loop
            console.log(userData);
          });
        });
      });
    });
    // failure, logs an empty object
    console.log(userData);
    return userData;
  }
}
```

I understand it's not working because userData is being returned before the above promises are being resolved. How can I get around this or what do I need to think about differently?

Answer (score 0):

Get the `th` elements by text, locate the user field values using `following-sibling` and construct a `user` object:

```
var user = {
    Title: row.element("//th[. = 'Title:']/following-sibling::td").getText(),
    Email: row.element("//th[. = 'Email:']/following-sibling::td").getText()
};
```

Example usage:

```
expect(user).toEqual(TestUser);
```

Note that `user` is an object where field values are promises, but, since [`expect()` is patched to resolve promises implicitly](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#protractor-adaptations), we are good to go - it should make the assertion once all promises are resolved.

---

If you want to abstract out the field names and make it reusable, use [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map):

```
var table = $("table.account-details");
var user = {};

table.all(".//th").map(function (elm) {
    var key = elm.getText(),
        value = elm.element(by.xpath("following-sibling::td")).getText();

    user[key] = value;
});

expect(user).toEqual(TestUser);
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response! I like populating the returned object with promises that will be resolved by the expect( ). However, I'm hoping to grab data from different tables throughout the site, so I'd like to abstract it so that it populates the new object's keys dynamically based on what it finds in a particular table's '<th>' values, instead of hard-coding it...

Comment: @christian.d could you check the update? (Not tested, but hope it would work for you). Thanks.